# How to remove specific elements in a numpy array (passing a list of values not indexes)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d numpy array and a list of values to remove (not indexes), how can I modify this code so that the actual values not indexes are removed

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
values_to_remove = [2, 3, 6]

new_a = np.delete(a, values_to_remove)
```

So what I want to delete is the values 2,3,6 NOT their corresponding index. Actually the list is quite long so ideally I should be able to pass the second parameter as a list

So the final array should actually be = 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9

Comment: Are the values unique? Do you need to remove in place or is a copy OK?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import numpy as np    

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
values_to_remove = [2, 3, 6]

for i in range(0, len(values_to_remove)):
     index = np.where(a==values_to_remove[i])
     a = np.delete(a, index[0][0])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1 4 5 7 8 9]
```

Comment: Quite complicated and inefficient method

Comment: True. Using a simple for loop might be too complicated for noobs.

Comment: For numpy, a loop is inappropriate most of the time. Here you loop for each item in the list, check the whole array and start over. I don't know how you would want me to phrase it but this is not a good approach.

Comment: Quick example of timing. 1M items, 1000 values to remove. It takes ~160ms with pure numpy vs ~6s with a python loop.

Comment: I see. Well, thanks for the comment. I felt a bit offended by your first comment but I got your point.

Comment: Apologies, by no means it was my goal, I only meant to comment on the substance of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

If you don't mind a copy:

```
out = a[~np.isin(a, values_to_remove)]
```

Output: `array([1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])`

To update in place:

```
np.delete(a, np.isin(a, values_to_remove))
```

updated `a`: `array([1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])`

Intermediate:

```
np.isin(a, values_to_remove)
# array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False])
```